# Tail Recursive ocaml function that outputs a List with numbers from n to 0;

Tags: ocaml, tail-recursion

This is what function should do:

```
to0from 5 = [5;4;3;2;1;0]
```

I'm trying to do this tail recursive but I can't find a way. This is what I've got:

```
    if n = 0 then
        0
    else
        let rec loop r = function
            | 0 -> r
            | _ -> loop (List.append r [n]) (n-1)
        in loop [] n;;
```

Any clues? Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem with what you have? Why can you not get it to work the way you want? Stack Overflow asks that questions be specific. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Well, @glennsl is right that you don't seem to be asking a specific question. So it's difficult to know how to help. But here are some comments.

Your code doesn't define a function at all. It just computes a value based on a global variable named `n`. You should flesh out your code into a definition of a function named `to0from` (from what you seem to be saying).

In the case that `n` is 0, your code returns an integer value of 0. In other cases it returns a list. This can't be right, and it could possibly be what you mean when you say you can't get your code to work.

Is the recursive call to `loop` in tail position? If so, I'd say that your code was tail recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a hint on how I would approach this...

```
let to0from d =
  let rec to0from_aux s acc =
    (* add code here to build list *) in
  to0from_aux 0 []
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-tail-recursive version is easy.

```
# let rec foo n =
    if n = 0 then [0]
    else n :: foo (n - 1);;
val foo : int -> int list = <fun>
# foo 5;;
- : int list = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 0]
```

You could use an accumulator. This doesn't represent that much of a change to the function.

```
# let rec foo ?(acc=[]) n =
    if n = 0 then List.rev (0 :: acc)
    else foo ~acc: (n :: acc) (n - 1);;
val foo : ?acc:int list -> int -> int list = <fun>
# foo 5;;
- : int list = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 0]
```

Or, as of OCaml 4.14, you could use `tail_mod_cons`.

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec foo n =
  if n = 0 then [0]
  else n :: foo (n - 1)
```

For yet another tail-recursive option, we can leverage the `Seq` module.

```
# let foo n =
    0 
    |> Seq.ints 
    |> Seq.take (n + 1) 
    |> List.of_seq 
    |> List.rev;;
val foo : int -> int list = <fun>
# foo 5;;
- : int list = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 0]
```